# Flutter just_audio play local audio file in windows application

Tags: windows, flutter, desktop, just-audio

I created a music player app to use with android which works fine, but now I wanted to use the app as a desktop application as well and I started to get some problems. (added just_audio_windows as stated in the docs)
The problem is, that when I want to load an audio source from my local device storage, i get the error 'sourceNotSupported'.

I checked the just_audio examples for reference, but there only streams and asset-files are used.
When I include the audio as an asset, it plays just fine, but I cannot load it from storage.
I loaded the file as a normal file (File(path)) and it exists and I can read and write to storage, so that should also not be the problem.
Is this a known issue or am I missing something? Including all the audios as assets is not an option for me :/

Comment: Different platforms have different levels of support. If you want that type of source (whichever source you're trying to instantiate) to be supported on Windows, you could make a feature request to the developer of just_audio_windows (via the just_audio_windows GitHub page).

Comment: Ahh thank you, I just saw that the state of 'read from File' for just_audio_windows is '(not tested)' so this might actually be not yet implemented!